# Automate width determination for included graphics

Tags: graphics, automation, scaling

For including graphics such as Matlab plots, I use `\includegraphics` from the graphicx package. Every time, I have to decide on some width and pass e.g. `[width=180mm]` to the inclusion command. This feels very arbitrary. How would I let LaTeX find the optimal width, assuming the graphic scales nicely without pixelation?

Comment: How do you define “correct”? The same as `\textwidth`?

Comment: @Caramdir: I just want it to look nice. `\textwidth` would probably be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like [Caramdir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/83/caramdir) suggests, use `\hsize` or `\textwidth` to scale your graphics to a consistent width:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\includegraphics[width=0.8\hsize]{some-file}
```

You could also define a dimension for flexibility that you could later easily re-define to a different width:

```
\newdimen\photowidth
\photowidth=0.8\textwidth % or \photowidth=180mm
...
\includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{some-file}
```

Comment: Good answer, but `\photowidth` doesn't need to be a dimension but can also be a macro which holds e.g. `0.8\textwidth`. This has the benefit (or drawback, depending on the point of view) that it adjusts if `\textwidth` changes afterwards, e.g. inside a `minibox`.

Comment: @Martin: I assume the advantage of a dimension is that you would use it as in `[width=0.5\photowidth]` but this wouldn't be possible if it were defined as macro, right? But I can see your point, too -- a dimension is defined once.

Comment: You are right, but eTeX comes to the rescue: `\def\photowidth{\dimexpr .8\textwidth\relax}` gives you both the advantages!

Comment: @Cristian Lindig: `\newdimen` is TeX command. How does it differ from `\setlength`? I prefer not to mix LaTeX and TeX commands just to keep my co-authors from asking the same question: what is the difference?

Comment: @Igor You are right. To stay within LaTeX you can use `\newlength{photowidth}` to introduce the new dimension and use `\setlength{photowidth}{180mm}` to set it.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant solution is to set desired width globally:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.75\textwidth}
```

Setting width locally as shown by Christian overrides global keys.